# Bind to concatenated text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

**Update:** I am using C#.NET with WinForms

If you have a decimal variable, e.g. a price, is it possible to bind the value of a text field (or label) to its value **plus** a text. In the price example, that could be a currency code. So in the example below I would like to creating a binding, so that the text field text was "5000 EUR". Is this possible, **without** creating a new property which returns the combination of the two?

Example:

```
// I want to bind to a concatenation of theese two variables...
public decimal price 
{
    get { return 5000; }
}

public string currencyCode 
{
    get { return "EUR"; }
}

// ...WITHOUT using this property
public string priceAndCurrencyCode 
{
    get { return price + " " + currencyCode; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bindings have StringFormat

```
Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat={}{0} EUR"
```

Or from code

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
        <Binding Path="Price"/>
        <Binding Path="Currency"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Or with fancy formatting

```
<TextBlock FontSize="12">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" Forground="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Currency}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using WinForms, is this method still viable?

Comment: Oh, i saw Binding and assumed WPF.

Comment: I understand. It was my bad not to clarify that. I wish I was working in WPF, but for now I am stuck in WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you have 2 different variables that does 2 different things. Using a third concatened one isn't wrong.

Whishing for lazy coding using some string format binding is essentially wrong. It won't help your further coding or maintanancability. When your 3rd property could have some uses elsewhere (binding to label or whatever).

I know that we (engineers/coders) are lazy by nature. But! Working a bit more to prevent further jobs, isn't it the best laziness?

More! Writing a third variables and using a StringFormat bindings will take you a comparable amount of time. (StringFormat may be even more consuming if you happen to learn it. Even if learning it is a good thing.)

Comment: It's not that I dislike my current solution that much, but you are right on the lazy part :-). I just wondered if there was a smarter method, but if there isn't, then that is just fine.

Comment: If you look at others answers, you will see that there is alternative. The problem lies in what you call "smarter". To my mind, keeping your first option is smart (maybe not the smartest).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MultiBinding for the textblock along with its StringFormat property and define the format as desired.